# Function to log arguments and return value of any function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, logging

I have implemented a function, which logs the inputs and outputs of any function, indenting the log based on the depth of the call stack:

```
(def depth (atom 0))

(defn logfun [fun]
       (fn [& args]
           (do
               (swap! depth inc)
               (println (str (apply str (repeat @depth " ")) ">>> (" fun " " args ")"))
               (let [result (apply fun args)]
                    (do 
                         (swap! depth dec)
                         (println (str (apply str (repeat @depth " ")) " <<< " result))
                         result)))))
```

Usage example:

```
(defn fact [n] (if (> n 1) (* n (fact (dec n))) n))
(def fact (logfun fact))
(fact 5)
```

Output:

```
 >>> (lang.core$fact@5eb14bce (5))
  >>> (lang.core$fact@5eb14bce (4))
   >>> (lang.core$fact@5eb14bce (3))
    >>> (lang.core$fact@5eb14bce (2))
     >>> (lang.core$fact@5eb14bce (1))
     <<< 1
    <<< 2
   <<< 6
  <<< 24
 <<< 120
```

Main questions:

- Is there a way to improve this function so that it is not dependent on global variables? (I have already attempted a solution based on [with-local-vars](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-local-vars) / [var-set](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/var-set) -- see below, but it seems to me that [they do not work as I wish they did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040754/clojure-with-local-vars-in-closure)).
- Are there any edge cases, for which the above function does not work?
- Are there any modifications by which this function can be made better adhering to Clojure best practices (besides somehow getting rid of the global state)?
- Is there a way to improve the output of the function names (e.g., instead of `lang.core$fact@5eb14bce` I would like to get `lang`) in a way that satisfies both conditions below:

  1. It must be available in the Clojure core language (no third-party libs, no usage of repl utilities)
  2. It must not use string manipulation (e.g. find the `@` and `$` characters via regexp and then strip away the parts before/after them).

In other words, I'm looking for something like: `(get-pretty-printed-function-name fun)`. (I already did some research, and found only solutions which do not satisfy the criteria above. Still asking, just in case ;) )

The attempted, **NOT WORKING** solution using var-set/with-local-vars:

```
(defn logfun [fun]
   (with-local-vars [depth 0]
       (fn [& args]
           (do
               (var-set [depth (inc @depth)])
               (println (str (apply str (repeat @depth " ")) ">>> (" fun " " args ")"))
               (let [result (apply fun args)]
                    (do 
                         (println (str (apply str (repeat @depth " ")) " <<< " result))
                         (var-set [depth (dec @depth)])
                         result))))))
```

EDIT: using [bound-fn](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/bound-fn), I get one step further, but unluckily it still does not do what is expected, as it seems that the variable `depth` in the closure is reset to zero upon every invocation of the returned function:

```
(defn logfun [fun]
   (with-local-vars [depth 0]
       (bound-fn [& args]
           (do
               (var-set depth (inc @depth))
               (println (str (apply str (repeat @depth " ")) ">>> (" fun " " args ")"))
               (let [result (apply fun args)]
                    (do 
                         (var-set depth (dec @depth))
                         (println (str (apply str (repeat @depth " ")) " <<< " result))
                         result))))))
```

Result:

```
 >>> (lang.core$fact@510da75f (5))
 >>> (lang.core$fact@510da75f (4))
 >>> (lang.core$fact@510da75f (3))
 >>> (lang.core$fact@510da75f (2))
 >>> (lang.core$fact@510da75f (1))
 <<< 1
 <<< 2
 <<< 6
 <<< 24
 <<< 120
```